# SSH login with key and home folder mounted at login

Tags: ssh, home

I have to connect to a server where the user home folders are mounted when a user logs in and unmounted after some time of inactivity. I don't know how they do it but with a simple `ls /home` I discovered it.

I set up a keypair to avoid typing the password each time I ssh into this server.
I checked `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server and the key is correct.
After the `ssh-copy-id` it worked without a problem, but the next day it asked me the password. The same day the next logins worked out of the box with the key.

So I'm guessing that the reason sometimes the key doesn't work is because my home folder (and so `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) is not yet mounted.

I've tried to `cat` `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but I don't have even read permission on it.

I can't guess any possible solution to this.

First attempt:

```
❯ ssh -v <username>@<host>
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/dpd-/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/dpd-/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for <host>
debug1: /home/dpd-/.ssh/config line 41: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 5: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/run/user/1000/kssh-316772-62ebc2b2eab867050f1276d08a9eed0a7d94401d" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to <host> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dpd-/.ssh/DEI type 3
debug1: identity file /home/dpd-/.ssh/DEI-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.7
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <host>:22 as '<username>'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:<hash>
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '<host>' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dpd-/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/dpd-/.ssh/DEI ED25519 SHA256:<hash> explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/dpd-/.ssh/DEI ED25519 SHA256:<hash> explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
<username>@<host>'s password:
```

Later attempt:

```
❯ ssh -v <username>@<host>
debug1: multiplexing control connection
debug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]
debug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2
OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/dpd-/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/dpd-/.ssh/config line 18: Applying options for <host>
debug1: /home/dpd-/.ssh/config line 41: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 5: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: multiplexing control connection
debug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
    if [ -z "$python" -o ython=$(command -v python))*" > /dev/stderr; cleanup_on_bootstrap_exit; exit 1; }4\\\\\\n\\\\\\041)"'  '/bin/sh
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
no-rc enabled
$
```

Comment: I do not see any possible solution. You would need to store the authorized key in some place it is always accessible, then configure sshd accordingly. If I understood correctly, you have no root access to the machine, so neither is possible.

Comment: After you successfully log into the server, does a listing of the /etc/passwd file (e.g., `cat /etc/passwd`) show your login name?  If not, then authentication of logins sessions is probably performed by a network service, and there may be provisions for checking that service for your ssh public key (instead of reading it from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).  Since the sshd_config file is not readable, you'll probably have to ask the server admins.

Comment: @SottoVoce you were right: my login name is not under `/etc/passwd`